Little hyperlink line next to a transparent button with a image overlayed on top of it
I've noticed a little line that appeared after I made a button so when you click on a social media logo it goes to that specific logo's social media that I have on that platform. I want to know how to remove this line.
Added a button to have a hyperlink to go to one of my social media's. Made the button transparent and removed its border. A little blue line should not have appeared after clicking on the button.
Here is a photo of what it looks like with a red circle around it:
enter image description here
Here is my code:
HTML:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../style.css">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>ZINCO</title>
</head>
<body>

    <!--Title Text-->
        <h1>ZINCO'S INNER MACINATIONS</h1>
   
    <!--Subtitle-->
        <h2>Welcome to the Socials!</h2>

    <!--Paragraph-->
        <p>You are currently on the <strong>Socials page!</strong><br>\/If your wanting to see more about me you should <em>check out</em> out the tabs below!\/</p>

        <header>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="../index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="socials.html">Socials</a></li>
                    <li><a href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        <header>
    <!--Social Links-->
            <ul>            
                <a href="https://zincodrone.tumblr.com/">
                    <li>
                        <button>
                            <img id="tumblr" src="../images/tumblr.png">
                        </button>
                    </li>
                </a>
                <li>
                    <img id="discord" src="../images/discord.png">
                </li>
            </ul>
    <!--Footer-->
    <footer>
        <p style=" position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; text-align: center;">ZINCO</p>  
    </footer>

</body>
</html>

CSS:
   
        body{
            background-image:url('images/star_blink.gif');
            background-position: center;
            background-size: cover;
            color: white;
        }
        header {
            font-family:'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
            text-align: center;
        }
        section {
            color:white;
            text-align: center;
            display: flex;
        }
        h1 {
            font-family:Impact, Haettenschweiler, 'Arial Narrow Bold', sans-serif;
            text-align: center;

        }
        h2 {
            font-family:'Lucida Sans', 'Lucida Sans Regular', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
            color:white;
            text-align: center;
        }
        h3 {
            font-family:'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
            color: white;
            text-align: center;
        }
        ul {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            list-style-type: none;
        }
        li {
            display: inline-block;
            margin: 20px;
        }
        p {
            font-family:'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
            color: white;
            text-align: center;
        }
        footer {
            color: white;
            text-align: center;
        }
        div {
            background: black;
            display: inline-block;
            width: 100px;
            margin: auto;    
        }
        #tumblr {
            max-width: 50px;
            max-height: 50px;
        }
        #discord {
            max-width: 50px;
            max-height: 50px;
        }
        button {
            background-color: transparent;
            border: none;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        /* unused style*/
        .column {
            flex: 33.33%;
            padding: 5px;
        }
        .row::after {
            content: "";
            clear: both;
            display: table;
        }
        #copyright {
            float: left;
            padding-left: 10px;
            padding-top: 10px;
            text-align: center;
            bottom: 0px;
            width: 100%;
        }


Your HTML is invalid. Only li are allowed as direct children of ul. Put the link inside the li.

Also, button/input are not permitted inside links. Either a link or a button, pick one, they do different things.

@Paulie_D thank you so much! If I could upvote your comment I would!

Your demo code doesn't replicate the issue. Make sure to post an example that actually shows the issue so that someone can debug it.

Please note that solutions go in answers, not in edits to the question.

It was improperly answered. The code now does show the issue. The answer is listed as the top answer. @ralph.m

The issue was the HTML being invalid.
The solution is to remove <button> from the code. While also having <li> being directly under <ul> as the HTML will be invalid if you do not have a <li> listed right below it.
Use the <a href="LINK GOES HERE"> inside of the <li> while grouped together under <ul> to have the same effect without the previously visited hyperlink line appearing.
HTML will look like this:
        <ul>            
            <li>
                <a href="https://zincodrone.tumblr.com/">
                    <img id="tumblr" src="../images/tumblr.png">
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <img id="discord" src="../images/discord.png">
            </li>
        </ul>

CSS will look like this:
    #tumblr {
        max-width: 50px;
        max-height: 50px;
    }
    #discord {
        max-width: 50px;
        max-height: 50px;
    }

